# What's the best way today to copy voice memos from iPhone to Mac WITHOUT using iCloud?

Tags: iphone, voice-memo

*"Maybe it's just me, but it's none of Apple's business."*  I don't want to share my voice memos with Apple by means of iCloud, and, until "iTunes" was mysteriously taken away, I didn't have to.  Strangely, the "Voice Memos" application on the Mac does **not** seem to have the ability to copy memos off the device, as the "Photos" application fortunately still does.

Comment: I recognize that the answer today might be a third-party ($$) utility and if so I would appreciate your experienced recommendations as an answer.

Comment: What's wrong with sharing via Airdrop with your computer?

Comment: What's wrong with just syncing the phone with the computer?  I have no use for Apple's Voice Memo utility, I use `Just Press Record` which actually works.  But unless Apple changed something, you sync the phone, the voice memos their application records just come over to your library.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the best alternative but you can use [AirDrop](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204144#share) to transfer voice memos.

First make sure Wifi and Bluetooth are turned on both on your iPhone and Mac. Then make sure AirDrop discovery is set to everyone or at least contacts only.

Now open the Voice Memos app on your iPhone and tap on a voice memo. Then tap on the three dots to appear and then on Share. Then select AirDrop from the choices to appear and then choose the option with your Mac’s name. The voice memo should then appear in your Downloads folder.

See the AirDrop option [in this article](https://www.igeeksblog.com/how-to-transfer-voice-memos-from-iphone-to-mac-or-pc/) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for this  – "awaiting further answers."  *Why can I no longer just use a piece of wire?*

Comment: Use the cable if you like.  You haven't described yet why that's a problem.